# My electrician left a spliced cable outside a junction box. How big a deal is this?

Tags: electrical, wiring, junction-box

I'm having some electrical work done to run existing lines through the joists so we can hang drywall on the ceiling. Some of the existing cable runs were too short so the electrician added a larger junction box with an access panel for those runs.

However, on one of the runs it is connected outside of a junction box as shown in the picture and will be buried once the ceiling is installed. The electrician says this is not a huge deal and the connector is made for this as a sort of last resort, but it makes me nervous that this was done after inspection. The inspection also pointed out several missing outlets to be up to code, which is part of why this was added but missing obvious things like that does not make me trust my electricians assurances that this is fine.

Is this a big deal? or am I making a big issue out of something because I don't understand it.

[image: Splice outside of junction box]

Comment: The inspector sees that and that electrician will find out just how big a deal it is.  Make him come back and do it right on his dime or have the inspector back.

Comment: The only in-wall (i.e., not in a junction box) code-compliant splice I know of is [this one](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tyco-Electronics-Romex-Splice-Kit-2-Wire-1-Clam-A22899-000/202204326). And that doesn't look anything like your picture.

Comment: @crip659 and OP shouldn't skip the inspector regardless of whether the electrician fixes it

Comment: That doesn't *look* like a Tyco splice...

Comment: Sanity check: I can't read the printing on those cables, but... Are we sure they're house current? The colors if the sheathing, plus what we can see of the connector through the tape, have me suspecting liw&voltage)signal cables such as network or speaker. In which case a buried splice would be fine.

Comment: Not only should you ask for your AHJ to come back for an inspection, but you may consider reporting this to the local licensing authority or, perhaps, calling the local union hall (presuming the guy is union) or the company this individual works for (if he's an employee of a larger company, not a small-time guy with his own name on the side of the truck). This is clearly a code violation and your electrician is trying to get away with not doing a proper job. It's possible that your inspector may make the relevant calls for you...

Comment: check everything else that the electrician touched

Answer (score 3):

> buried once the ceiling is installed. The electrician says this is not a huge deal

Clear violation of NEC 300.15 requiring a box or conduit body at each splice point and 314.29 requiring accessible wiring.

> The electrician says this is not a huge deal and the connector is made for this

Clear violation of NEC 334.40(B) which requires a single device and requires exposed wiring.  The other exception is for repairs, which this project is not.

What you have in the photo looks like a taped set of Ideal Spliceline brand butt splices for pairs of individual conductors.

> Is this a big deal?

This is remarkably unprofessional.  Start by contacting the AHJ and finding out what would be the consequences of failing a second rough inspection.  It is not the same for every locality.  This will give you an idea how to proceed and whether you'd be better served by hiring a different electrician.

Comment: The local inspector would, I think, be _most_ interested in an electrician trying to get away with this kind of work and have the homeowner not question it...

Answer (score 1):

I am not an electrician, nor an inspector. Having said that, it sounds like you don't trust the electrician's work and it seems suspicious to add this *after* the inspection, almost as if hoping another inspection won't happen to uncover bad work?

I suggest this:

- pay for a second inspection when the electrician has completed his work. This will address any concerns or doubts you might have about work quality.
- Get agreement from the electrician that any work needed after this second inspection is not paid by you, and will be followed by a third inspection also not paid by you. This will motivate the electrician to do solid work that meets the requirements, and prevent an unending repeat of inspections and insufficient corrections.

Answer (score -2):

"Bringing up to code" is neither obvious nor required for the type of electrical work you describe (moving wires into concealed wall/ceiling space), unless it was specified in an agreement with the electrician. Your inspector could well be making unwarranted demands. There exist devices that are approved for making concealed splices in the sort of cables you show, perhaps you could give some information as to what it is ... your photo is useless for that. Moreover, it seems there is plenty of slack in those cables to put the splice in a box located at the edge of the adjacent joist/rafter, and it being a quick and easy job to do so makes one wonder why it was not done.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by “not required”, as before the electrical would have been compliant (no splices outside of a junction box or concealed splices), and now it presumably would not be compliant, for those reasons.  Is your argument that electrical work should not follow code, or that the person requesting service should explicitly ask for compliance, or that the work appears to be compliant?

Comment: there exist splice systems that are listed for buried in wall use.